# Is it possible to show our own adds before playing YouTube activity?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm new to this concept actually. I'm using Android YouTube SDK for playing YouTube videos. I doubt is before playing video I need to display my own video add is possible to do that. I already search in Google but no answer found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play your ad via youtube player api, the answer - no, you can't. But at the end of your ad playback you can call play() on the YouTubePlayer instance.

Comment: Hi thank u for u response, actually before opining Youtube activity i want to play my own ad after that open youtube activity is it posible? @Arsalan Intogsrov

Comment: @chantihoney How do you play your ad?